# Nopcommerce 4.5 - Create a plugin to disable reward points for a specific customer role

Tags: asp.net, .net, nopcommerce

I need to create a plugin to disable reward points for a specific customer role.

The plugin must give me the option in the reward points settings to give me [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSM3n.png) to select customer role(s).

Any clue on how I can do it?

No idea how since I am new to Nopcommerce.

Answer (score 2):

The same plugin configuration has been used in Nop.Plugin.DiscountRules.CustomerRoles. You can get all the functions and code from that plugin.

[Nop.Plugin.DiscountRules.CustomerRoles GitHub link](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/tree/develop/src/Plugins/Nop.Plugin.DiscountRules.CustomerRoles)

Before starting development of the plugin, you can see the source code and get ideas from default NopCommerce plugins

[NopCommerce Default Plugins GitHub link](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/tree/develop/src/Plugins)